# Jenkins+RTC: Is any jenkins plugin having functionality for checking for changes in the RTC server without loading it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, rational-team-concert

The Script SCM plugin for Jenkins seems a potential solution for checking for changes in the RTC server without loading it.
Plugin page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+SCM+Plugin